# c++ get functions caller class name

Tags: c++, templates, singleton

I created singleton class with a function "log", so it can be called from any other class.
When somebody calls log() i want know the class name of the caller.

```
template<typename T>
void log(LogLevelType logLevel, const char* format, ... );
```

...

```
template<typename T>
inline void Logger::log(LogLevelType logLevel, const char * format, ... )
{
    std::string className = typeid(T).name();
}
```

This works but i'm still not satisfied with the way you have to call this function:

```
    Logger::get()->log<MyClass>(LOG_INFO, "Registering function %s successful.", "blub");
```

Can i make this more generic for example with

```
log<this*>
```

instead of

```
log<MyClass>
```

?

Comment: You could also pass `this` as a `T const*` parameter to the `log` function, so that you have automatic template parameter deduction.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can, but you need to use `decltype`:

`log<decltype(*this)>` is the same as `log<MyClass>` assuming that `this` is a pointer to an instance of `MyClass`.